# Ajax modal form window not loading

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I already had success in ajax loading a form into a modal window with Ctools but now it fails and I do not why. Maybe someone can help me?! The problem: I create a link on a page which should open a form in a modal window. With another (Views created) page it did work fine: I click on the link and the form is correctly rendered in a modal window. In the following case it seems to be all the same - the only difference is that another form is used and the ajax links are not created by a Views page but a custom page callback. But when I click on the ajax link the modal window is opened - but the throbber keeps rotating and nothing happens. No form is shown in the window - just the throbber graphic.

As I can see when hacking into functions like ajax_render() that the output is correctly built into an array usable by ajax_render()... there are no error message anywhere, neither in Drupal database logs, reports or server error logs. Additionally the browser gives no JavaScript error or warnings.

This is the menu_hook defining the page callback for the ajax link:

```
 $items['foodlog/existing/%ctools_js/%foodlogentry/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit your foodlog entry',
    'page callback' => 'foodlog_edit_form_ajax',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4),
    'access callback' =>  'foodlog_edit_form_access',
    'access arguments' => array(3),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK  
  );
```

This is the ajax page callback:

```
function foodlog_edit_form_ajax($js = NULL, $foodlogentry, $action) {

  if ($js) {
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
    );
    $form_state['build_info']['args'][] = $foodlogentry;
    $form_state['build_info']['args'][] = $action;

    $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('foodlog_edit_form', $form_state);    

    if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
      $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
    }

    // Return the ajax instructions to the browser via ajax_render().
    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();    
  }

  // go on: if no $js -> render the form
  else {    
    return drupal_get_form('foodlog_edit_form', $foodlogentry, $action);
  } 
}
```

And here is the code where the ajax link is rendered (just the part of the page callback, where it happens):

```
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();

$actionlinks = l(t('edit'), 'foodlog/existing/nojs/'. $entry['flid'] .'/edit', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-modal', 'ctools-modal-foodlog-modal-style') ) ) );
```

The result is the correct link like

```
<a href="/foodlog/existing/nojs/9813/edit" class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-foodlog-modal-style ctools-use-modal-processed">Bearbeiten</a>
```

The JavaScript files are loaded, no caching is enabled, no aggregation. As I mentioned the same is working on another Views page where I create such a link by rewriting a views field. Just the form is another one. The form is rendered when I simply call the URL directly in the browser - there seems to be some trouble somewhere when Drupal sends all the stuff to the browser.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: I'm only idea is unfortunately not very helpful to your issue directly. But I see all that (good) custom code and just think this would have been a ton easier: https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: on my page I use the jQuery Flot plugin in order to create some charts. For one of the charts there was an error on the page where I wanted to open a form in a modal window. When I solved this error the modal window was working as expected... JavaScript is a weird thing!